# Create table in word doc using docx4j in specific bookmark:

Tags: java, docx4j

I’m creating a table in specific bookmark location (means it's adisplay table in word doc), but after converting word to PDF it can't show table in PDF because of bookmark is inside a `w:p`!!

```
<w:p w:rsidR="00800BD9" w:rsidRDefault="00800BD9">  
  <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="abc"/>
  <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
</w:p>
```

Now I want to find the paragraph (using the bookmark), then replace the paragraph with the table.

Does anybody have any suggestion?

Here is my code:

```
    private void replaceBookmarkContents(List<Object> paragraphs,  Map<DataFieldName, String> data) throws Exception {

    Tbl table  = TblFactory.createTable(3,3,9600);
    RangeFinder rt = new RangeFinder("CTBookmark", "CTMarkupRange");
    new TraversalUtil(paragraphs, rt);

    for (CTBookmark bm : rt.getStarts()) {

        // do we have data for this one?
        if (bm.getName()==null) continue;
        String value = data.get(new DataFieldName(bm.getName()));
        if (value==null) continue;

        try {
            // Can't just remove the object from the parent,
            // since in the parent, it may be wrapped in a JAXBElement
            List<Object> theList = null;
            if (bm.getParent() instanceof P) {
                System.out.println("OK!");
                theList = ((ContentAccessor)(bm.getParent())).getContent();
            } else {
                continue;
            }

            int rangeStart = -1;
            int rangeEnd=-1;
            int i = 0;
            for (Object ox : theList) {
                Object listEntry = XmlUtils.unwrap(ox); 
                if (listEntry.equals(bm)) {
                    if (DELETE_BOOKMARK) {
                        rangeStart=i;
                    } else {
                        rangeStart=i+1;                         
                    }
                } else if (listEntry instanceof  CTMarkupRange) {
                    if ( ((CTMarkupRange)listEntry).getId().equals(bm.getId())) {
                        if (DELETE_BOOKMARK) {
                            rangeEnd=i;
                        } else {
                            rangeEnd=i-1;                           
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }

            if (rangeStart>0) {

                // Delete the bookmark range
                for (int j=rangeStart; j>0; j--) {
                    theList.remove(j);
                }

                // now add a run
                org.docx4j.wml.R  run = factory.createR();
                run.getContent().add(table);
                theList.add(rangeStart, run);
            }

        } catch (ClassCastException cce) {
            log.error(cce.getMessage(), cce);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: May be you need to customize conversion from doc to pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with blindly replacing a bookmark inside a paragraph with a table is that you'll end up with  w:p/w:tbl (or with your code, w:p/w:r/w:tbl!) which is not allowed by the file format.

To avoid this issue, you could make the bookmark a sibling of the paragraph, or you could change your code so that once you have found a bookmark inside a paragraph, if you are replacing it with a table, you replace the parent p instead.

Note that bookmark find/replace is a brittle basis for document generation.  If your requirements are other than modest, you'd be better off using content controls instead.

Comment: Please Jason could you suggest how to replace the parent p with table in this code.

Comment: Assuming the p is given by bm.getParent(), it should be in your List paragraphs, in which case its just replacing an item in a list (Java collections).

Comment: As you have to told, I’m replacing paragraph to table using java collections, it work in convert into DOCX file (but not to display table border). When convert to PDF its Throw Exception: